How can I open a URL within a container on both Windows and macOS?
I'm currently developing an exe(for windows and MacOs) using Flutter, Specifically, I want to implement the functionality to open URLs within containers. However, I'm encountering challenges in achieving this. Currently, I am using desktop_webview_window to open a URL, but it is displaying in a separate window and I don't want that. Could someone guide me on how to implement the ability to open URLs within containers seamlessly across these platforms?
Any insights, recommendations, or sample code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I tried:
Utilized the desktop_webview_window package to open URLs within the application.
Expected behavior:
I expected the URLs to open within the container of the application, seamlessly integrating with the UI.
Actual outcome:
However, despite my efforts, the URLs consistently open in a separate window, which disrupts the user experience.

maybe try another package like https://pub.dev/packages/webview_dart
